# switch with built in solenoid

Tags: switches

I am trying to source some toggle switches that also have a built in solenoid and can effectively toggle themselves. Like what they sometimes have on sound mixer boards for automation. Basically a relay that can be manually flipped. But what exactly would you call that? I cannot find it on mouser, etc. Not looking for a specific product reccomendation just what the darn thing is called.  Thanks!

Comment: This is obviously a device that _could_ exist, and I know the automation motorized faders are common, but are you sure you've actually seen one of these switches? Ones I've seen are just momentary push buttons or spring-to-center toggles which turn on or off a circuit and indicator LED, which are also controlled by software.  That's so much cheaper and almost as effective, leading me to think that the mechanical variant may not be readily available.

Comment: Do you need to flip both ways automatically, or would self-resetting be enough?

Comment: Need it to flip both ways